# How do I set working directory for latex input

Tags: texstudio, miktex2.9, directory

I operate on windows, I am using MIKTEX and Texstudio. All the time I need to imput files like `graphics` or `bibliography` I do define the path l**ike this:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}
    \begin{figure}[H] 
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5cm]{C:/Users/user/Documents/LATEX/blockbootstrap}
        \caption{Block Bootstrap in Picture}
        \caption*{Source: \cite{ElAnbari2015}}
        \label{fig4}
    \end{figure}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{~}
\frametitle[]{~}
\def\newblock{}
%\begin{block}[allowblockbreaks]{~}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{C:/Users/user/Documents/LATEX/economia}
%\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see that `C:/Users/user/Documents/LATEX/` is expected to be my `working directory` as shown in line `8` and `19` of my `MWE`. How can I set this once and for all such that I will just put the file name alone and not the path each time I need to? **like this:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{~}
\begin{block}{~}
    \begin{figure}[H] 
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5cm]{blockbootstrap}
        \caption{Block Bootstrap in Picture}
        \caption*{Source: \cite{ElAnbari2015}}
        \label{fig4}
    \end{figure}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{~}
\frametitle[]{~}
\def\newblock{}
%\begin{block}[allowblockbreaks]{~}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{economia}
%\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the same search path is used as for `\input` so you never usually need to use the full path so normally you just need `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{blockbootstrap}` (don't specify both height and width or it will distort the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your `****.tex`  file in the same directory that `economia.bib` and `blockbootstrap.***`!!

Probably you are working with a new temporal file that ***is not*** yet in the supposed working directory. If you try to compile a unnamed document, then is saved to temporal name like  `texstudio_PCb739.tex` in the temporal directory (I do not use Windows, not sure if it should be `C:/WINDOWS/Temp` or another), where is not the bibliography nor the image.

Once saved in `C:/Users/user/Documents/LATEX/` you can use relative paths to that directory, as:

- `\includegraphics{img/foo}` if there a image `foo.jpg`  in `C:/Users/user/Documents/LATEX/img` or ...
- `\includegraphics{..\foo}` if that image is in `C:/Users/user/Documents` or simply ...
- `\includegraphics{foo}` if the image is in `C:/Users/user/Documents/LATEX/`